# Cassandra 3.x Triigger : Getting "Clustering Key and Its Value"

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, scylla

I need to find a way to get not only partion key but also clustering key through Partition object. I am aware of how to get the actual partition key and its value from the object but not "Clustering keys"

Here is what I have tried so far: I have tried using "unfilteredIterator" but that only returns regular columns (not the clustering key/value)

My C* table looks like the following

> ```
> CREATE TABLE user.foo (
> ac_id timeuuid,
> mapping_id timeuuid,
> country text,
> state text,
> PRIMARY KEY (ac_id, mapping_id) ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (mapping_id DESC) ...
> ```

My code so far:

```
public static String getKeyText(Partition update) {
    List<Map<String, String>> listOfMaps = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    CFMetaData cfm = update.metadata();
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    try {
      UnfilteredRowIterator it = update.unfilteredIterator();
      while (it.hasNext()) {
          Unfiltered un = it.next();
          Clustering clt = (Clustering) un.clustering();
          Iterator<Cell> cells = update.getRow(clt).cells().iterator();
          Iterator<ColumnDefinition> columnss = update.getRow(clt).columns().iterator();
          while(columnss.hasNext()){
              ColumnDefinition columnDef = columnss.next();
              Cell cell = cells.next();
          }
      }
  } catch (Exception e) {

  }
}
```

Goal is to get ac_id and mapping_id column names & values

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it with the following:

```
      public static String getKeyText(Partition update) {
    List<Map<String, String>> listOfMaps = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    CFMetaData cfm = update.metadata();
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    String localKey = getKey(update.partitionKey().getKey(), cfm);
    // go over all columns and only add those that are clustering and partition keys
    List<ColumnDefinition> partitionKeyColumns = cfm.partitionKeyColumns();
    for (ColumnDefinition partitionColumn : partitionKeyColumns) {
      map.put(partitionColumn.name.toString(), localKey);
    }
    //Now work on clustering keys ONLY
    try {
      List<ColumnDefinition> clusteringKeyColumns = cfm.clusteringColumns();
      UnfilteredRowIterator it = update.unfilteredIterator();
      while (it.hasNext()) {
        Unfiltered un = it.next();
        Clustering clt = (Clustering) un.clustering();
        ByteBuffer[] clusteringKeyValues = clt.getRawValues();
        int i = 0;
        for (ColumnDefinition column : clusteringKeyColumns) {
          map.put(column.name.toString(), cfm.getKeyValidator().getString(clusteringKeyValues[i]));
          i++;
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    listOfMaps.add(map);
    // Now process Clustering keys
    return gson.toJson(listOfMaps);
  }
```

However, I am not sure if this is an optimal way to solve this

Comment: The code from `sstabledump` tool can be an example code: https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.11/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/tools/JsonTransformer.java#L349